# Is /a/g in {}/a/g a regex or a division?

Tags: javascript, regex, grammar, language-lawyer, ecmascript-5

I am writing a [JavaCC-based parser for JavaScript](https://github.com/highsource/javascript-codemodel) ([ECMAScript 5.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1)) and have an interesting corner case with regular expressions. Here it is.

Consider the following statement:

```
{}/a/g
```

My question: From the *specification* point of view, should it be interpreted as

- `ObjectLiteral` divided by `Identifier a` divided by `Identifier b` *or*
- `Block` followed by `RegularExpressionLiteral /a/g`?

For instance, Chrome interprets it as the latter and other parsers as well.

**From the specification point of view, is `/a/g` in `{}/a/g` a regex or a division?**

Here is what I think to be a [relevant part](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7) of the specification:

> There are no syntactic grammar contexts where both a leading division
>   or division-assignment, and a leading RegularExpressionLiteral are
>   permitted.

Quoting [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11766233/303810) on the [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519596/when-parsing-javascript-what-determines-the-meaning-of-a-slash):

> The division operator must follow an expression, and a regular
>   expression literal can't follow an expression, so in all other cases
>   you can safely assume you're looking at a regular expression literal.

My understanding is that `{}` *is* an expression. [ObjectLiteral](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5), even an empty one is a [PrimaryExpression](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1). So the following `/a/g` must be a division, not a regular expression literal.

Or am I wrong with this?

Comment: What makes you think {} is an expression, or that this is just a single statement? An opening brace is usually interpreted as the start of a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `{}` is not an expression in this case. Quoting the relevant parts of the annotated standard: http://es5.github.io/#x12.4 "An `ExpressionStatement` cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a `Block`". In your case, `{}/a/g` is a block, followed by an expression statement consisting of a regular expression literal.

Comment: Cool, this is what I was missing.