# Unambiguous increment and adding results in error

Tags: javascript, syntax, increment, addition, operator-precedence

When playing around with JavaScript syntax it struck me that the following code will throw an error in SpiderMonkey and V8 engines:

```
var a = 1, b = 1;
a++++b;
```

This to me is strange, since the following works perfectly fine:

```
var a = 1, b = 1;

a+++b; // = 2; (Add a and b, then increase a)
// now a == 2 and b == 1

a+++-b; // = 1; (add a and -b, then increase a)
// now a == 3 and b == 1
```

In addition, the following would be nonsensical code:

```
var a = 1, b = 1;
a++ ++b; // throws an error
```

My argument is now that if `a+++b` is equivalent to `a++ + b`, and not to `a+ ++b`, and `a+++-b` is equivalent to `a++ + -b`, then `a++++b` can only be interpreted as `a++ + +b` in order for it to be valid JavaScript code. 
Instead, the engines insist that `a++++b` is interpreted as `a++ ++b`, by [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

This to me is in contrast with the logic that the engines implements using the `/` symbol, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519596/when-parsing-javascript-what-determines-the-meaning-of-a-slash), to distinguish between division and regular expressions. An example

```
var e = 30, f = 3, g = 2;

e/f/g; // == 5

e
/f/g; // == 5

/f/g; // is equivalent to new RegExp("f","g")
```

Here the argument is that because `/f/g` does not make sense as division in the last line, it is interpreted as a regular expression.

Obviously the `/` symbol gets a special treatment, in order to distinguish between division and regular expressions. But then why do `++` and `--` not get a special treatment as well? (That is, outside operator precedence)

A second question is why operator precedence is not called *only* when the code is has multiple valid interpretations.

Answer (score 2):

In the code `a++++b` you have two distinct statements: `a++` and `++b` with nothing to combine them.  The `+` operator in the context of `a++ + +b` is actually a type converter (meant for turning strings into numbers) and has a different [order of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) which follows the others in the list.

Comment: Yes, the `+` is also used for "casting" - for example `+"10"` will convert that `string` type to a `number` type

Comment: @CoryG Could you elaborate your answer? I fail to see how this this different from what I have already discussed in my question.

Comment: @TrenchCode Sorry if I was brief, I've been writing a parser, tokenizer, and abstract syntax tree system for a custom language modeled very closely against JS for the past several months so I tend to take for granted how much of a PitA it was to wrap my head around the precedence initially.  JS is designed to be parsed on the fly very quickly, as a result you don't have a clear precedence like in many other languages, that list is about as good as it gets without sifting through the spec.  Things like `//` comments and `+` type converters are parsed before and after that whole list (cont)

Comment: @TrenchCode It's relatively simple for a parser to do an off-the-bat iteration through the text (or do it in conjunction with a single parsing loop preceding everything else) to determine what is inside or outside of a string then what is inside or outside of a comment so they do those before checking for operators (why bother doing syntax parsing if it's just text in the form of a literal or a comment?)  Likewise, converters are kind of a hacked-on-after-the-fact feature of JS because things were supposed to be type-invariant but it didn't quite work out that way in practice so they don't fit

Comment: @TrenchCode Trying to standardize JavaScript (or any language, programming or spoken) into a very strict syntax without loopholes rarely works perfectly (I can't actually think of a single instance in spite of knowing a few dozen) - they are designed to describe arbitrarily complex things and be extensible while the people who write them inherently can't know all the use cases - beyond version 1 of a language you get inconsistencies.